# Timestamp truncation in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, sqoop, truncate

While exporting data from various RDBMS to Hive, 0's at the end of milliseconds in timestamp is getting truncated.
For example-

```
Source                     Hive
2015-03-27 23:42:44.300 => 2015-03-27 23:42:44.3
2015-03-27 23:42:44.000 => 2015-03-27 23:42:44.0
2015-03-27 23:42:44.350 => 2015-03-27 23:42:44.35
```

I've 2 columns in every table, `creat_dt` and `updt_dt` which is having this issue. Temporary solution I applied is to sqoop data using a 2 step process.

1. Sqoop(eval) table structure and using sed command, I add cast
   command to convert into proper timestamp format and hold the list of
   columns in a variable.
2. Sqoop(import) the data from source by passing column values from step 1.

I would like to know if there is a direct method or command which I can specify in the sqqop which will help me achieve my objective.

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might work.

while sqooping cast it as string and sqoop it and if you want date in hive cast it again as date using to_date function.